# Force web root to use http

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I have some rewrites set up to force half the site's pages to http and half https. This all works including https://site.com/index.php, however just https://site.com will not rewrite to http.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^about\.php|contact\.php|down\.php|faq\.php|find\.php|forgot\.php|home\.php|index\.php|listings\.php|viewpost\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How can I edit this to include the root? I've tried adding /| to the condition, but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed a pipe without the slash

```
RewriteRule ^|about\.php|contact\.php|down\.php|faq\.php|find\.php|forgot\.php|home\.php|index\.php|listings\.php|viewpost\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```